# How do I freeze my credit?

Tags: united-states, credit-report, fraud, identity-theft

If freezing your credit is a better way to protect your identity and the associated credit that goes along with it, how do I freeze my credit?

Comment: Very interesting.  Of course, the first thing that came to mind was that old trick/cliche of freezing your credit cards in a block of ice. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's cool.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Freezing your credit is as simple as contacting each of the credit bureaus via their websites and asking for a freeze.  Remember, don't get monitoring or a credit alert, get a credit freeze.

Depending on the state you live in, there will be a charge to freeze and unfreeze your credit.  You will need to unfreeze your credit before you apply for a loan or anything else that somebody would access your credit report for.  While you can possibly spend up to $10 per incident, this is probably worth it.

You will be given a secret key that you can use to unfreeze your credit, so store that in a safe place so you don't forget.

If you have a police report from a case of identity theft, you can do the freezing and unfreezing for free.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_freeze

Comment: The FTC has a [Credit Freeze FAQ](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0497-credit-freeze-faqs) that provides some detail on what it is and how to do it.