# To protect against fraud in Canada do I need to go with either Equifax / TransUnion or both?

Tags: canada, fraud, alerts, equifax

As per this [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54680/credit-freezes-arent-available-in-canada-what-options-are-available-to-protect), to protect against fraud, one needs to put a credit alert on TransUnion and Equifax.  Isn't it enough to put a fraud alert on just one of them?  Why do we need to put it on both these organizations?

<sub>p.s: reason for this question is because my wife lost her purse with all of her ID cards and I set up a fraud alert on Equifax for a few $$$ / month.</sub>

Comment: Wife had the same thing happen to her. Put an alert on both Equifax and TransUnion. They are separate entities. Also make sure to deal with fraud accounts when they pop up.