# Got Notice My Personal Information May be Compromised

Tags: canada, identity-theft

For anyone who may believe this is Phishing, it is not.

I got a notice from a company saying that an HR employees car got broken into and it may have personal data of mine. I haven't had a job with this company in probably over 4+ years.

Other than monitoring my credit with Equifax (I got a year free from Home Depot), is there anything I can do? Why was my personal information on the personal laptop anyway.

It's a weird case, but just wanted some insight.

Edit: Sorry, i'm from Canada.

Comment: Could you please add a tag for your country?  I'd assume US, but I am just ethnocentric enough to do so.  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the United States, even if you didn't suffer an attack, go ahead and freeze your credit.  Nobody can open lines of credit as if they are you, and you will have ELIMINATED the worst kind of ID theft.

[How do I freeze my credit?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4996/how-do-i-freeze-my-credit)

Somebody can steal your payment card info and use it, but you can dispute that.  Somebody can open a line of credit as you, and even if you have monitoring, it is a pain to remove those accounts and clear your good name.

Further, monitoring only works after then fact.  A credit freeze stops trouble before it can begin.

Comment: That is a good idea. I can do my own research for freezing in Canada. Thanks.