# Who are the consumer credit reporting agencies in Canada?

Tags: canada, credit-score, credit-report

I'm trying to determine what credit freeze and reporting options are available in Canada.  In the United States it seems [freezing your credit requires contacting *all* of the credit bureaus](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/4997/7251).  I have not, however, found a conclusive and exhaustive list of consumer [credit reporting agencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_bureau) in Canada.

Wikipedia implies that [TransUnion Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TransUnion_Canada) and [Equifax Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equifax_Canada) are the only [two Canadian credit reporting agencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_bureau).  However, there are no substantiating citations.

1. **Are Equifax Canada and TransUnion Canada the *only* consumer credit reporting agencies in Canada?**

[This CBC article uses the term "national credit bureau"](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/how-to-check-your-credit-report-1.1185975):

> You can ask for a free copy of your credit file by mail. There are two national credit bureaus in Canada: Equifax Canada and TransUnion Canada.

2. **Are there consumer credit reporting agencies in Canada who are not "national"?**

Answer (score 1):

1. They are the only agencies cited in the Office of Customers Affairs - here https://www.ic.gc.ca/eic/site/oca-bc.nsf/eng/ca02179.html and everywhere else in their website:

> "Along with the credit histories of millions of other people, your
>   credit history is recorded in files maintained by at least one of
>   Canada's major credit-reporting agencies: Equifax Canada and
>   TransUnion Canada."

2. I never heard of any other credit reporting agency in Canada and a search didn't return any other different from Equifax and TransUnion.